# IOS touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded, issue with multiple image views

Tags: ios

So as I have my code now, there is two image views. One on top of the other. You draw on the top image, and when the touches end the top image is transferred to the bottom image and 'saved'.

With my current implementation this only allows for one image to be drawn on the screen, because if I add another set of image views and try to draw on it, the program will crash.

So I was wondering if there is a way for the touchesBegan, moved, and ended methods to recognize which set of image views I am trying to draw on, and to draw on the approriate ones.

```
//Drawing Functions
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UIImageView *drawTemp = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:topImageTag];

    mouseSwiped = NO;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:drawTemp];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UIImageView *drawTemp = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:topImageTag];

    mouseSwiped = YES;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:drawTemp];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawTemp.frame.size);
    [drawTemp.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, drawTemp.frame.size.width, drawTemp.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush );
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeNormal);

    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    drawTemp.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [drawTemp setAlpha:opacity];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastPoint = currentPoint;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UIImageView *drawTemp = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:topImageTag];
    UIImageView *drawMain = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:bottomImageTag];

    if(!mouseSwiped) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawTemp.frame.size);
        [drawTemp.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, drawTemp.frame.size.width, drawTemp.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, opacity);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        drawTemp.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawMain.frame.size);
    [drawMain.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, drawTemp.frame.size.width, drawTemp.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
    [drawTemp.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, drawTemp.frame.size.width, drawTemp.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:opacity];
    drawMain.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    drawTemp.image = nil;
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You may want to try UIGesture recognizes.

Comment: So programatically add a gesture recognizer for each set of image views? Is that what you had in mind by reccomending gestures?

Comment: Yes. And you can use pan gesture recognizer for tracking.

Comment: Okay, I'll have a look. Thanks